# How to load combobox using SQL like function?

Tags: c#, sql, search, combobox, sql-like

I can find my data using the following command

```
SELECT name FROM emp WHERE name  LIKE '%ahmed%'
```

and get result :

```
name
======== 
Md.Momin 
Sarkar 
Ahmed
```

same sql code I have use combobox and load data

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM emp WHERE name LIKE '" + '%' + comboBox1.Text + '%' + "'", con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());

}
con.Close();
```

under the combobox system do not return result 
**but  without like function normally i can load data using the code**
How can i have search string in combobox??

Comment: Put a break point on your sql command line and check what you are passing to the query

Comment: Please **don't** use string concatenation to build SQL queries, use parameters instead.

Comment: No offense, but your English is a little broken and the question is hard to understand.   Do you mean that you are having trouble loading the data with the SQLReader if you use a `like` filter on your SQL query?  Are you trying to just load the combobox and let the user filter what it contains?

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense, you using your `comboBox1.Text ` for query, then you adding results back to your `comboBox1` ...

Comment: my comboBox data many type of string value  i need search option when i have type some string

Comment: i can load SQL Reader easily  i need search  data in comboBox1 from database

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help, but unfortunately have lack of information, so I assume :

- Your application is either WPF or Windows Form
- You are using SQL server
- You start with a blank ComboBox, type in, click a button and then fill the combobox with the result
- You don't have a problem when not using 'LIKE'

**What you need to do is :**

- Place the **break point** in the line with : "SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();"
- Run in debug mode, and do your thing
- When the break point is reached, **add the variable "cmd" in the watch list**
- See what's the content of its **CommandText** property, and then copy it
- Open the SQL query window and try to run the query there

If everything is going well, may be there's something out-of-the-frame which has something to do with this issue somehow.

Just want you to know that I have tried your codes above and it's running well completely.

I hope you to get a hint or something.

[image]